# Calculating Totals per members in an MDX Calculated Member

Tags: mdx, member

I'm new to MDX and trying to create a calculation that will provide the total of a member. I have tried the Root function but it gives me the grand total for all the members, I just want the total per member.
This is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. Team 1 Closed 12 Calls within 1 Day, Team 1 has a total of 30 calls
2. Team 1 Closed 14 Calls within 2 Days, Team 1 has a total of 30 calls
3. Team 2 Closed 10 Calls within 1 Day, Team 2 has a total of 15 calls
4. Team 2 Closed 15 Calls within 2 Days, Team 2 has a total of 15 calls

How can I create a calculated measure in SSAS so it stores the total number of calls per Team,  for Team 1 will be 30 and for Team 2 will be 15, so I can use it to calculate the % of calls closed within a number of days, i.e. :

1. % Of Calls closed for Team 1 within 1 Day = (12/30)*100 = 40%
2. % Of Calls closed for Team 1 within 2 Days = (14/30)*100 = 46.66%
3. % Of Calls closed for Team 2 within 1 Day = (10/15)*100= 66.66%
4. % Of Calls closed for Team 2 within 2 Days = (15/15)*100 =100%

I have tried the Root function but it gives me the grand total for all the members i.e. 15 + 30=45
Thanks

Comment: Please add your attempted `mdx` to the question

Comment: I have deleted it. I think I did something like this: SUM (Root ([Team].[Team Name]), [Measures].[Calls Closed])